# How to store image in Wordpress using Woocommerce Api's in Laravel

Tags: wordpress, laravel, woocommerce

I am using Woocommerce api's in Laravel. I have Facing issue to store image in Wordpress. On This stage i have no idea what i do. **I have no idea about code to write.** Anyone can help how can i store image from using Laravel in Wordpress. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should give you an idea where to start.

Woocommerce has a good PHP Library for their API. I found a Laravel package which is a wrapper for Woocommerce API, https://github.com/Codexshaper/laravel-woocommerce

**1. Install the Woocommerce plugin in WordPress and generate an API key and Secret.**
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-rest-api/

**2. Install the package in Laravel**

```
composer require codexshaper/laravel-woocommerce
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=woocommerce
```

**3. Follow Laravel-Woocommerce documentation for configuration and usage**
https://codexshaper.github.io/docs/laravel-woocommerce/

**4. Remember to update your **.env**, with the information you got from **step 1****

```
WOOCOMMERCE_STORE_URL=YOUR_WEBSITE_URL
WOOCOMMERCE_CONSUMER_KEY=API_CONSUMER_KEY
WOOCOMMERCE_CONSUMER_SECRET=API_CONSUMER_SECRET
```

**5. Setup a controller in Laravel**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Codexshaper\WooCommerce\Facades\Product;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    public function create(Request $request){
        try{
            //@todo idealy, the data should be coming from $request->all() or something
            $data = [
                'name' => 'Simple Product',
                'type' => 'simple',
                'regular_price' => '10.00',
                'description' => 'Simple product full description.',
                'short_description' => 'Simple product short description.',
                'categories' => [
                    [
                        'id' => 1
                    ],
                    [
                        'id' => 3
                    ],
                    [
                        'id' => 5
                    ]
                ],
                'images' => [
                    [
                        'src' => 'http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/T_2_front.jpg'
                    ],
                    [
                        'src' => 'http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/T_2_back.jpg'
                    ]
                ]
            ];

            $product = Product::create($data);

            dd($product); //@todo

        }catch(\Exception $e){
            dd($e); //@todo
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks I am trying it